# How to log on to a 3rd party DNS Service provider and write a MX record

Tags: c#, dns

I have these three values :

1. DNS service provider details
2. UserName
3. Password

I need to log on to the DNS service providewr and create a MX record. I do not know anything on this. Can some one please point me in the right direction.

I am using C# as my language. Any links or sample code will surely help.

Comment: answer to self: no, this isn't. Those are something different: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want a provider which supports RFC [2136](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2136.txt)
and implement that protocol into your client, or call an external helper program appropriately. Other ways, like provider web interfaces, don't follow a consistent method for adding records to zones - they're meant for interactive use by humans, not by automated processes.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a third party DNS provider?
DNS providers typically have a web admin interface for managing your domain's DNS records.

You simply have to login to the website and create an MX record.